To renew deck or to replace it?
My deck is around twenty years old.
The wood is becoming old and cracked.
I wonder if it is repairable or shall I replace the wood with new pieces.
If it is repairable, how can I? Shall I paint with a material or what?
Note the upper wood will be replaced for sure.
I am asking about the posts.


I attached some pictures.

If everything is 20 yrs old replace it all.  Would you be ok with new decking and 20 year old posts and framing?

@RMDman Shall I replace the beams & joists as well?

If your budget allows for total replacement of all components, then that is what you should do.  Besides we in internet land have no idea what condition the entire structure is in.  If in real doubt, call a deck building company and offer to pay for them to inspect it.

Checking is really not a big deal, if the wood was properly treated 20 years ago. Unless there are structural issues actually happening, save your moeny for when they do happen. See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/282376/18078 if it's not rotten and collapsing, it's just a deck, somewhat aged, still functional.

"Checking", in case you aren't familiar with the term, refers to splits along grain lines. Checking will make the wood age faster, and does weaken it somewhat, but ignoring it, sanding it down, and/or filling it (depending on your skills and patience) are often sufficient

It appears that your deck is close to the ground. Have you checked the joists, supports and ledger board. Based on my experience those components go even before decking and posts. If you can't see under it you may have to pull a few pieces of decking to get a good idea of the condition of the support structure.
